# Проблема передачи данных из PHP в js + json (MVC)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, zend-framework-3

Задача: переместить js код +json из view в отдельный уже существующий джс файл для прохождения XSS защиты на сервере. Код для отрисовки графика на странице через ajax.
Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

**Controller:**

```
$tester = 'various-';
 $view = new ViewModel([
            'tester' => $tester,
        ]);
        $view
            ->setTemplate('path/to/file')
            ->setTerminal(true);

        return new JsonModel([
            'success' => true,
            'html' => $this->viewRenderer->render($view),
            'tester' => $tester,
        ]);
```

**VIEW:**

```
<span class="strong-border-text">Test</span>
        <div id="<?=$tester?>"></div>
```

**custom.js**

```
$.get('/path/to/file/' + z + '/' + x, function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                $('#more-' + x + '-' + z)
                    .find('.panel-body')
                    .html(data.html);

                $('#more-' + x + '-' + z)
                    .data('loaded', 1);

                $(data.tester)
                    .highcharts({
                    chart: {....
...
```

Данный код не хочет отрисовывать график, ошибок в консоли нет.
Но стоит убрать из view  и custom.js переменную заменив на
`<div id="various-"></div>` во вью и

```
$('#various-')
```

в js,
как всё работает отлично.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть ошибка или куда смотреть чтобы ее отловить?

Comment: `#` забыли, видимо

Comment: `$('#'+data.tester)`

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка ввиду неопытности. Действительно забыл #.
$('#'+data.tester)
Всем комментаторам спасибо большое за помощь.